# how to split one column into multiple?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a data frame with two rows and one column. I would like to split one column into eight columns.

Input:

```
                                                                              V1
1    Source                Model  terms     Gamma     Component    Comp/SE   % C
2    animal                10600  10600  0.336134      0.266547      14.26   0 P
```

I like this output:

```
         V1                   V2     V3        V4            V5         V6  V7 V8
1    Source                Model  terms     Gamma     Component    Comp/SE   % C
2    animal                10600  10600  0.336134      0.266547      14.26   0 P
```

Comment: You probably didn't read your data properly using `read.csv` or something. Try reading it using `read.table`. You'll probably need `fill = TRUE` too

Comment: as mentioned by David it is likely you're reading the table in wrong. `read.table` allows you to set the delimiter `read.table(file = "path/to/file", sep = "")` ,in your case the default should work but you can change sep to anything (i.e tab would be `sep="\t"`)

Comment: Also use `header = T` to let `read.table` know that the first line contains your column names.

Comment: I have done it. But my data have one column and I want to split it into multiple columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. Consider `df` is your data.frame:

```
> output <- data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]+")))))
> names(output) <- paste0("V", 1:8)
> output
      V1    V2    V3       V4        V5      V6 V7 V8
1 Source Model terms    Gamma Component Comp/SE  %  C
2 animal 10600 10600 0.336134  0.266547   14.26  0  P
```

just do what @DavidArenburg suggests on his comment: `read.table(text = df$V1)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg you really hit in the ballseye! What a shame!